# How do I make 'man ascii' work on Fedora 11

Tags: linux, fedora, manpages, ascii

Upgrading from Fedora 9 with a full reinstall off the non-developers CD image,
then installing various packages.  `man ascii` doesn't work -- what do I need
to install to get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't come bundled with the default man pages, to install it:

```
yum install man-pages
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My Debian system has this installed at `/usr/share/man/man7/ascii.7.gz` (in section 7 of the manual), and was installed with the package `manpages`.  On Debian systems, tools like `apt-file` and `apt-cache` can search uninstalled packages for particular files.

According to the [Fedora Package Database](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/collections/id/21?packages%5Ftgp%5Fno=2&packages%5Ftgp%5Fordering=name&%5Fcsrf%5Ftoken=8fbf89542a2bfe182a418d2f12716bf3da92145e&packages%5Ftgp%5Flimit=100) (linked in tj111's answer), there is a `man-pages` package.  Install that if you don't have it already.  You might check for additional core documentation packages.

**edit**: John T confirms:  `man-pages` is the package you want.

Answer (score 0):

The package `ascii` doesn't appear anywhere in the [Fedora 11 Package Database](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/collections/id/21?packages_tgp_no=2&packages_tgp_ordering=name&_csrf_token=8fbf89542a2bfe182a418d2f12716bf3da92145e&packages_tgp_limit=100), however [`asciidoc`](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/name/asciidoc?_csrf_token=8fbf89542a2bfe182a418d2f12716bf3da92145e) does.  If that's what you're looking for, make sure you have `asciidoc` installed.